# Neural Network on Android?

Tags: android, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a dataset of some disease. It contains the symptomes.

How can I train model on my local machine and than use it in Android app? (user will input symptomes and app preidcts result - yes or no)

Comment: You can't until you share your code

Comment: Step 1: Post your code.
Step 2: Elaborate your question.
Step 3: Get help.
Step 4: Enjoy.

Comment: Should able to use something like `TensorFlow` - https://jalammar.github.io/Supercharging-android-apps-using-tensorflow/

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly it would be great to use TF, but found example only with photos

Comment: Then do more research to understand TF is more than Deep Learning for images. And there are tons of non-image projects available.